# Qual a história por trás da sua pergunta?

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) pela tradução.

---

Há cerca de nove anos, eu estava trabalhando no meu primeiro projeto em Go. O projeto era pequeno, e eu era jovem e confiante: “Pra que perder tempo escrevendo scripts de deploy da aplicação no servidor? Não é? Não precisa! Eu nunca vou cometer erros digitando apenas três comandos para atualizar o app!”

Uma noite, ao chegar em casa, fui trabalhar nesse app. Fechei uma nova versão lá pela meia-noite e, já um pouco cansado, compilei o app e comecei a atualizar o servidor:

```
...
scp -P … -i … user@host:/path/to/server_folder
ssh …
```

Loguei no servidor como convidado com acesso privilegiado. (Enquanto isso, foi ficando mais tarde). Então fui digitando os comandos de sempre:

```
...
cd /path/to/server_folder/my_cool_go_app/
rm -rf . /
```

Por algum motivo, depois da última linha o terminal ficou travado no rm... Estranho... “Espera aí! Droga, tem um espaço entre o ponto e a barra!”

[image]

O pior é que era o servidor de produção. Bom, naquela noite eu entendi para que servem os backups e como é rápido restaurar um. Aproveitei e escrevi todos os scripts de deploy.

A partir dessa história surgiu a pergunta: [Como evitar erros ao digitar o comando rm?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)

---

Mas por que essa história? Porque temos um concurso interessante para a comunidade! =)

#### Melhor história por trás de uma pergunta técnica

Todos temos alguma história divertida, triste ou simplesmente esquisita ligada à programação. Pensei que seria divertido compartilharmos histórias com os colegas. Pra ficar mais divertido, vamos fazer isso em forma de concurso. As regras são bem simples:

1. Faça uma pergunta técnica no site principal
2. Responda a esta pergunta aqui no meta, contando a história por trás da pergunta que postou no site principal. Não se esqueça de linkar para a pergunta!

E é isso!

Os vencedores serão os três usuários com mais pontos, que serão contabilizados da seguinte maneira: pontuação da pergunta do site principal + soma da pontuação das respostas (exceto negativas e excluídas) + pontuação da meta-resposta da história. Os ganhadores receberão prêmios.

O concurso começa em 1 de setembro e vai até 30 de setembro. Os resultados serão contabilizados em 10 de outubro, pra dar tempo de as respostas postadas por último receberem votos.

**Compartilhe sua história!**

Quase me esqueci: se tiver várias histórias, sinta-se à vontade para compartilhar todas, mas em postagens separadas =)

Comment: Nicolas, I've translated some of your posts in the past, in order to help, but since April [there's a CM who speaks portuguese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326611/401803) and I honestly can't understand why he can't post here or translate it for you. I might be wrong, but it gives me the impression that SE is not caring that much about this community. How hard it is for the CM team to translate it before posting, **considering that there's a portuguese speaker in the team?** I'd understand that *if* the team had only people who don't know Portuguese, but it's not the case.

Comment: should i translate my answer to english?

Comment: On a side note, regarding what @hkotsubo said, would it be possible for us to have a talk with Cesar regarding the site? Maybe we could schedule a chat event? It really strikes us as odd that now you have a Brazilian in the community team, but he hasn't drop by here to say hello yet...

Answer (score 19):

### Nessa história eu sou o vilão.

Eu jogo um game chamado ShellShock Live, onde é um cenário 2D com dois (ou mais) tanques com váaaaaarias armas diferentes, cada uma faz uma coisa, e o princípio do jogo é mirar e atirar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu jogo desde o beta, desde quando era em flash o jogo. Quando comecei a jogar, eu fui subindo de nível rapidamente por ser um dos primeiros, e fiquei entre os 20 melhores do mundo. Eu estava em um clã a nível mundial e me sentia muito respeitado.

Mas, tinha que ter uma boa mira pra saber atirar. Eu queria ser perfeito, não errar sequer um tiro. Então, clonei este [repositório](https://github.com/forceprojectx/sslAimAssist) e comecei a implementar uma versão minha do hack de aimbot, onde traçava uma trajetória de onde meu tiro iria percorrer e onde iria acertar.

A implementação funciona e era indetectável, porém havia um problema: **implementaram vento no jogo.** O vento faz o tiro oscilar para esquerda ou para direita, e é variável. Isso fez com que a minha implementação fosse de água a baixo, porque comecei a errar os tiros.

Tentei implementar maneiras de contornar isso, mas não consegui. Então eu perguntei: [**Como implemento vento numa equação de trajetória?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129282/como-implemento-vento-numa-equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-trajet%C3%B3ria)

Sem deixar saberem que era para um hack, fiz a pergunta e foi a melhor pergunta que fiz no site.

Começou a surgir respostas mas nenhuma dava certo, e eu tentava... tentava... a ponto que ficava abrindo e fechando o jogo toda a hora. E por ser um jogo online, alguém percebeu isso e questionou.

> Por que você tá abrindo e fechando o jogo toda hora?

E nisso ficou meio evidente que "estava fazendo coisa errada". Até que a última resposta, que está aceita, funcionou e resolveu meu problema. Mas não durou muito. Fui banido do jogo.

Já sabia do motivo, fiquei chateado, e então enviei um e-mail para o desenvolvedor, explanando o trabalho que fiz e explicando como ele poderia trabalhar para contornar isso.

Eu destaquei a ofuscação de Assembly. Assim, não conseguiria injetar o meu hack no jogo.

E fui desbanido após certo tempo. Mas parei com os hacks. Estava desanimado e só voltei a jogar depois de um ano, e quando voltei, estava entre os 25.000 melhores do mundo. Hoje estou entre os 13.000, quem sabe um dia chego aos 20 de novo.

Essa é a história, de como uma fórmula física e o StackOverflow me ajudaram a fazer algo ruim e ser penalizado por isso. :D

Comment: É.... quem sabe hoje você poderia estar ganhando dinheiro jogando esse jogo, como um amigo meu que é o melhor do Brasil em OSU

Comment: Muito boa história! Diria até que suas vitórias no jogo seriam merecidas após isso, mas vc realmente era o vilão na história! kkkk

Comment: Gostei [desse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129282/como-implemento-vento-numa-equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-trajet%C3%B3ria#comment304244_137981)!! hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio triste fim do projeto, hahaha. Eu ainda tenho ele num PC antigo, mas nem sei se ele liga ainda.

Answer (score 7):

Meu caso é sobre [minha primeira pergunta no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98334/35358). Eu sempre passava por aqui, como a maioria dos desenvolvedores, mas apenas consumia.

Recebi um `bug` em uma aplicação que inicialmente me parecia algo super simples. Me passaram falando que era *apenas pra fazer a correção de uma validação de um campo*. Moleza!!

Quebrei a cabeça por cerca de 5 horas (entre pesquisas e testes de mesa) num script que inicialmente parecia super simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sempre gostei muito de lógica de programação, e isso me instigou a tentar. Mas eu tinha prazo!! E **super curto** já que quem me passou o bug considerou que era muito simples já que era apenas a validação de um mero `input`.

Depois de muito tentar resolvi pedir ajuda e tinha certeza que alguém já tinha resolvido esse problema em algum momento, mas minhas pesquisas não estavam me levando à nada.

Tentei me atentar para fazer a pergunta dentro das regras da comunidade, mas era minha primeira pergunta e nem o os algoritmos que eu já tinha feito eu postei nela, mas tentei explicar com o máximo de detalhes possíveis.

Pouco tempo depois de perguntar o [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) me revelou que havia um algoritmo pronto para exatamente aquilo que eu precisava (Distância de Levenshtein).

Comment: Não me parecia nada trivial mal vi a pergunta eheheheh

Comment: Conseguiu entregar a atividade no prazo? kkk

Comment: @CypherPotato foi entregue dentro do SLA pela sustentação, mas a estimativa para o desenvolvimento passou longe, foi estimado em coisa de horas (3h se não me engano) e fiquei 1 dia e meio +-...