# As “melhores” histórias por trás das perguntas no site

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) pela tradução.

---

Uma pergunta sobre Stack Overflow é apenas a ponta de um iceberg. A meu ver, mesmo uma simples pergunta no site pode ser precedida por uma longa série de tentativas malsucedidas e pesquisas dolorosas de novas maneiras de resolver um problema (e às vezes conversas difíceis com o gerente de projeto). Por exemplo, depois de excluir todo o servidor de produção com o comando `rm -rf. / *`(causado por um erro de digitação, um espaço entre `.` e `/`), o que gerou a pergunta «[Como evitar erros de digitação ao remover um diretório no terminal?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)».

Ao longo de setembro, [os usuários compartilharam](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7925/17539) suas histórias que precederam suas perguntas sobre o Stack Overflow em português. Muito obrigado a todos que participaram! De acordo com os resultados, o maior número de votos (uma história + pergunta e todas as respostas) obteve:

- [CypherPotato: Como implemento vento numa equação de trajetória?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7927/17539)
- [George Wurthmann: Contar a quantidade de caracteres alterados em um campo input](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7931/17539)

A publicação sobre o concurso no MSE “[Qual é a história por trás da sua pergunta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334861/274323)”

O concurso terminou, mas não nos impede de nos divertir! Sinta-se à vontade para compartilhar sua história agora mesmo no [MSOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7925/17539) or [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334861/274323).